# Where to Vote to Approve an Edit/Revision

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, revisions-list

Where on [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) does one with enough reputation go to be part of voting to accept or deny Revisions (aka 'Edits')?

Comment: You are still ~200 rep short of this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Suggested Edits review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits). You can access that and other review queues under the "review" option in the top of each page.